# click on div: do this, click on link inside div: do something else

Tags: jquery, select

i have some div element that scrolls to another position, when you click on it.
but now i also want to include links into that div..
now when i click, the link gets called plus the div scrolls.
i want to prevent the div from scrolling, when hitting a href..

any idea?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/honk1/HfYmv/2/)
(this example is not scrolling at all, but i want it to alert the href, when click on an href element, or stay undefinded, when no href element is around..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need two onclicks, one on the div, one on the a in the div. Something like this, perhaps? http://jsfiddle.net/HfYmv/8/

Comment: niiice. sometimes the obvious is just not clear enuff. thanks!!